# Possible to use "tbody data=" to provide custom bindings to only some of the td's in a tbody?

Tags: html, knockout.js, binding

I created a custom Keybinding named enterKey, that allows the user to press enter to call a function such as `data= ko(enterKey: 'save')` to allow the user to press enter to save, instead of a click event.

I have:

```
tbody
  tr
    td
    ...
    td
    ...
    td
    ...
    td
    ...
```

I want to apply this enterKey data bind to only the last 2 td's.  When I try to add on the enterKey databind in the td itself, it doesn't work for any of them.  But when I place the enterkey binding in tbody like:

```
tbody data= ko(enterKey: 'save')
```

it allows every td cell to hit enter to save.  That's nice but I only want this functionality to work for the last 2 cells.

Is there something I can add to tbody to maybe force it to ignore the first 2 cells?

Sorry if I am asking this a hard or wrong way.  Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: `data= ko(enterKey: 'save')` doesn't look like a Knockout data binding. Are you using something different?

Comment: Hey Michael, yeah its knockout data binding I just have shortcuts added to make the code simpler. data= ko()is essentially. data-bind="enterKey: save"

Answer (score 0):

I do this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.enterkey = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel) {
    var callback = valueAccessor();
    $(element).keypress(function (event) {
        var keyCode = (event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode);
        if (keyCode === 13) {
            callback.call(viewModel);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
}};
```

then for each td in binding:

```
<td data-bind="enterkey: doStuff" />
```